# Feign for downloading file

Tags: spring-boot, feign, openfeign

I am trying to find a simple way to use Feign to download a csv file (retaining the filename).

What is the easiest and cleanest way?

The multipart solution on the feign-form github page is verbose and isn't working for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify the exception that you got ?

Comment: I just am looking for a solution that produces a simple decoding

Comment: For the record my exception was: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;] and content type [application/csv]

Answer (score 9):

Feign client:

```
import feign.Response;

@FeignClient(value = "some-service")
public interface Client{
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value ="/download")
   Response downloadFile();
}
```

Usage of Feign Client:

```
final Response response = client.downloadFile();
final Response.Body body = response.body();
final InputStream inputStream = body.asInputStream();
```

You should check if response is 200, if not, throws exception.
File name should be in headers